# ¿Cómo capturar body de una HTTP response en Python?

Tags: python, http, webhook

Estoy recibiendo en mi consola sólo el estado (200) de un webhook de pipedrive, pero necesito obtener el body de dicha respuesta en python.

Comment: hazlo con la libreria requets

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta! Por ejemplo, si el end point de mi webhook es una url "X", debería usar esa url para sacar los datos de ahí?

Comment: listo hice una respuesta explicando

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lo puedes hacer ya sea que se haga una peticion a tu servidor como al hacer una peticion a un endpoint
**obteniendo body de una peticion a nuestro servidor**

```
#aqui se usa flask para el servidor
from flask import request #importamos request de la libreria flask

# de esta forma obtenemos la propiedad name de un json 
# enviado a nuestro servidor
@app.post('/'):
     name = request.json['name']
```

**obteniendo respuesta de un endpoint**

```
import requests #importamos request

#hacemos la peticion
req = requests.get('https://url.com')
code = res.status_code #obtiene el estado de la respuesta
contType = req.headers['content-type'] # obtenemos el content-type
res = req.json() #obtenemos la respuesta en formato JSON
#ppuedes hacer cualquier peticion incluso enviando datos con la propiedad payload

print(res) #imprimimos la respuesta
print(code) #imprimimos el codigo de estado
```

instalas la libreria con `pip install requests`
aqui te dejo la [documentacion](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/)

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo! Tomaré esto y lo aplicaré :)

Comment: ok, edite la pregunta añadiendo la documentacion, puedes usar `req.text` para ver la respuesta en texto plano en caso tengas algun incoveniente leyendola

Comment: Super! Entonces es requests no request? Estaba buscando ese paquete. Muchas gracias por toda la información amigo! Llevo poco tiempo en esto, así que estoy lleno de dudas siempre!

Comment: me di cuenta que cometi un error en la primera parte asi que lo arregle, en tu caso creo que buscas algo como la segunda parte asi que si, es `requests`. Si tienes otra duda no dudes en realizar tu pregunta